# Network issues in Centos 5.6 guest at esxi

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-esxi

I have installed esxi with some VM's.

Ubuntu server was the first and was fine. With his own external ip.
CentOS 6 was installed and configured the network with other external ip. Everything ok.
After, I installed CentOS 5.6 to try virtualization over virtualization(xen). And i tried to configure the network, like the ubuntu server and Centos 6. I have the same config files in centos 6 and in centos 5.6.

When i ping in the centos 5.6 where is the problem, i get this:

```
Ping (8.8.8.8)...
From xx.xx.xx.xx Destination Host Unreachable
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip of the server and it is also the broadcast. You can think it is bad configured, but in the official manual of ovh, and in centos 6 the broadcast must be the ip.

It's really frustrating, because in others virtual machines it works that ip, but in centos 5.6. I tried to create 1 more centos 5.6 but it's the same, is like centos 5.6 has problems with esxi...

PD: When i'm configuring the centos 5.6, the others virtual machines are down...

No iptables, no selinux.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You have CentOS 6 running as a VM on ESXi and  then run CentOS 5.6 as VM inside the virtual CentOS 6 machine?

Comment: Nono, sorry. I have esxi, and inside the CentOS 5.6. I talked about CentOS 6 because my network was ok there. You can forget it. Thanks.

Comment: So you set the VM IP and broadcast to the same value?!

Comment: Yes, but it's well configured. I configured it in others vm's and are ok. And in the officials how-to they say that. Btw, someone said the same so i commented that line, is unnecesary.

Comment: no one thinks anything?